# Copy folders from one directory to another in R

Tags: r, file, directory, copying

I have two folders (say "A","B") which are in a folder (say "Input"). I want to copy "A" and "B" to another folder (say "Output"). Can I do this in R?

Comment: take a look at `?file.copy`

Comment: That is for individual files right. I want to copy two folders at once.

Comment: From in file.copy takes a vector of files, so you can copy two folders at once.

Comment: I am able to copy the files in the folder but not the folder

Answer (score 31):

Copying your current directory files to their new directories

`currentfiles` is a list of files you want to copy
`newlocation` is the directory you're copying to

If you aren't listing your current files, you'll need to loop through you're working directory

```
file.copy(from=currentfiles, to=newlocation, 
          overwrite = TRUE, recursive = FALSE, 
          copy.mode = TRUE)
```

This is for deleting your old files

```
file.remove(currentfiles)
```

Comment: I am able to copy the files in the folder but not the folder. I removed the recursive part of the code.

Comment: Argument `overwrite` is logical according to ?file.copy documentation. Change to either `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Comment: as OP didn't react I edited the post, I've set overwrite to `TRUE`, meaning this action may be destructive, use wih caution or set to `FALSE`

Answer (score 23):

I am late. This is my simple approach that gets things done.
In R,

```
current_folder <- "C:/Users/Bhabani2077/Desktop/Current"
new_folder <- "C:/Users/Bhabani2077/Desktop/Ins"
list_of_files <- list.files(current_folder, ".py$") 
# ".py$" is the type of file you want to copy. Remove if copying all types of files. 
file.copy(file.path(current_folder,list_of_files), new_folder)
```

Comment: you've got wrong name for current folder in `list_of_files` creation

Comment: Sorry. My Bad. Fixed the typo now.

Comment: This answer is clearer and therefore more useful for newbie.

Answer (score 4):

All of the solutions I've seen to this question seem to imply a Unix based operating system (Mac & Linux).  I think the reason that the response(s) didn't work for OP is that OP may be on Windows.

In Windows, the definition of a file is just that, a file, whereas Unix defines a file as a file or directory.  I believe this may be why `file.copy()` is not working, based on my understanding of the "File Manipulation" R documentation - arguments inputted to `file.copy()` for the "from" field must be files (not directories), but can be either files or directories for the "to" field.

Answer (score 3):

**fs** package provides an alternative solution that answers the original question precisely

```r
library(fs)
```

I've created "input" folder with the structure proposed in my working directory

```r
fs::dir_tree()
#> .
#> +-- copy_folder.R
#> +-- copy_folder.Rproj
#> \-- input
#>     +-- A
#>     |   +-- C
#>     |   \-- exampleA.txt
#>     +-- B
#>     |   \-- exampleB.txt
#>     \-- D
fs::dir_copy("input/A", "output/A")
fs::dir_copy("input/B", "output/B")
fs::dir_tree()
#> .
#> +-- copy_folder.R
#> +-- copy_folder.Rproj
#> +-- input
#> |   +-- A
#> |   |   +-- C
#> |   |   \-- exampleA.txt
#> |   +-- B
#> |   |   \-- exampleB.txt
#> |   \-- D
#> \-- output
#>     +-- A
#>     |   +-- C
#>     |   \-- exampleA.txt
#>     \-- B
#>         \-- exampleB.txt
```

Note that we worked in the general case that "input" folder contains other folders and files than folder “A” and “B”.

If "input" folder only contains folders “A” and “B”, one line of code would be enough:

```r
fs::dir_copy("input", "output")
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>